# In Jumu'ah Salah, can 1 imam recite the khutba and another imam lead the prayer?

Tags: salat, jumuah

When we pray Jumu'ah salah, the Khutba is recited. Can 1 imam recite the khutba and another imam lead the salah?

*<sub>(Please include in your answer different views)</sub>*

Comment: This is a discussed matter some may allow it others not, others may even consider such a juma'h void.

Comment: Ok, I don't mind in the answers that they include different views.

Comment: I found an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes it is permissible but it isn't Sunnah

---

Imaam Ibn Qudaamah (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:

> “Section: the Sunnah is for the same person to lead the prayers as gave the khutbah, because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to do both himself, as did his successors (the khulafa’).
>
> But if one man gives the khutbah and another leads the prayer for a valid reason, this is permissible. This is what Ahmad stated…because if it is permissible for someone else to take over leading the prayer for a valid reason, then this applies even more so in the case of the khutbah with the prayer.
>
> If there is no reason, then Ahmad (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:
>
> ‘I do not like it if there is no excuse.’
>
> The reason why it is not liked may be because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to do both of them, and he said,
>
> ‘Pray as you have seen me praying’ (Reported by al-Bukhaari and Ahmad),
>
> and because the khutbah takes the place of two rak’ahs. The reason why it is permissible may be because the khutbah is separate from the prayer, as if it is two prayers.”
>
> **(al-Mughni, part 2, Kitaab al-Jumu’ah: Fasl: yatawallaa al-salaah man yatawallaa al-khutbah. See also: al-Badaa’i’, 1/262, al-Sharh al-Kabeer, 1/499).**

Based on the above, it is permissible but it isn't Sunnah.

And Allah knows best.

**End quote**

---